# how can i change WP main archives loop to sort by name or title

Tags: posts, wp-query, sort

I've got the following code which i found somewhere else i use it for pagination.

I don't understand all of it although I've read codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query several times. they seem to speak about new queries.

```
global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite, $numposts;
$wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;  
$pagination = array(  
    'base' => @add_query_arg('page','%#%'),  
    'format' => '',  
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,  
    'current' => $current,  
    'show_all' => false,
    'mid_size' => 5, 
    'type' => 'plain',
    'prev_next'    => True,
    'prev_text'    => __('[<< Prev]'),
    'next_text'    => __('[Next >>]'),
);  
if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) 
    $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged' );  

if ( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']) ) 
    $pagination['add_args'] = array( 's' => get_query_var( 's' ) );
```

Is there a way to change this so it will also sort the posts by lets say title or name or id or any other type of sorting ?

Comment: Seems adding `$posts = query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=title&order=asc');` is what i was looking for.

Unless anyone knows of a better way ?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to do any alterations of the main query. The main query happens before the template is loaded, using `query_posts` just overwrites that original query, which is a waste of resources:

```
function wpa82795_archives_orderby( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'asc' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa82795_archives_orderby' );
```

See [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) for other conditions you can test for to limit the application of your new query parameters. You can set any query arguments that are available for [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: I have created a custom field directly in the `posts` table. How can i sort it with this field? It does not seem to work with your code

Comment: you added a column to the posts table? that's probably not a good idea. it won't work because WordPress has no knowledge of your column. use post meta instead and sort by that meta key.

Comment: I was looking at the code; yup you are right, wp does not know this field and would require changing the core to do so.. so I will use meta data instead.. do you have an example how to add my meta field to the main wp_query and sort by this field?

Comment: ok got it I think: 
`$query->set( 'meta_key', 'custom_order' );`
`$query->set( 'meta_type', 'NUMERIC' );`
`$query->set( 'orderby', 'customn_order' );`